# Date input Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this very nice regex that I got from the net which makes my date inputs `dd/MM/yyyy`, but now I would like to get it to only be `ddMMyyyy`, but I can't seem to get the `/` removed. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

```
(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((2902(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing all \/ but it seems a few should have stayed, can you tell me why you added the `[0-9]+` to the end because I tested it without it and it still works the same. Thanks

Comment: I removed it, it was a leftover from the previous regex i was testing in the browser, :) sorry about that.  You should use the one i pasted above now.

Answer (score 2):

Is [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method not appropriate?

Comment: I can only send a regex to the input field, I have no control over the rest of the screen. And the whole idea is to allow a user to not have to input the / when capturing a date. If it was an edit mask then this would have been fine. unfortunilty they did not go that route. but thanks

Answer (score 1):

When removing instances of /, make sure you also remove the accompanying \ which is used for escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all the \/.

Comment: I did that at first but it seems there was a few that I should not have deleted. Thanks

Comment: o crap, you were right, don't know why it didn't work first time round